# Need to write a query with the below specification

Tags: sql

Need to write a query to select the records which were active from a particular date ,current status can be active or inactive which belongs to category say students.

Table ==>

```
id category date-from    date-to     status 
1 student   01/01/2015   12/01/2020  active 
1 student   12/01/2020   01/01/9999  active 
2 employee  01/01/2018   01/01/9999  active
3 student   10/05/2015   01/01/2016  active
3 student   01/01/2016   01/01/9999  inactive
```

want to get the students who were active as on 01/06/2015,but there current status can be active or inactive
need to get their current status ,id ,current status

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Also, you should explain the data model.  Presumably, this is tiled in time, but you don't explain that.

Comment: Have tried exists but the category filtering is not working

Answer (score 0):

If you want the students that were active on a given date, you can just filter the table, like so:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where 
    date '2020-06-01' >= date_from 
    and date '2020-06-01' < date_to 
    and status = true
    and category = 'student'
```

You did not tell which database you are using - this uses the standard syntax to declare date literals.

Comment: .  This doesn't actually answer the question:  "want to get the students who were active as on 01/06/2015 . .  need to get their current status ,id ,current status".

Answer (score 0):

```
select t.*
from t
where t.type = 'student' and
      t.date_to > current_date and
      exists (select 1
              from t t2
              where t2.id = t.id and
                    t2.status = 'active' and  
                    date '2015-06-01' >= t2.date_from and
                    date '2015-06-01' < t2.date_to
             );
```

Note:  This uses standard SQL syntax.  Date functions and constants are notoriously database-dependent.  But the idea should work in any database.